# iOS: Initial interface orientation[UIInterfaceOrientation] being ignored in plist

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

I'm trying to set the initial orientation for my app to be 
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

I cant get

```
'Initial interface orientation'[UIInterfaceOrientation]
```

to override the first item in array of

```
'Supported interface orientations'[UISupportedInterfaceOrientations]
```

I noticed an iphone app always starts with 'Portrait (bottom home button)'.and the array is:

```
'Supported interface orientations'[UISupportedInterfaceOrientations]

Portrait (bottom home button)

Landscape (left home button)

Landscape (right home button)
```

Which is as expected.

If I turn PORTRAIT HOME BOTTOM button on Summary page OFF THEN BACK ON
then the order of the array changes and Portrait (bottom home button) moves to the bottom.

```
Landscape (left home button)

Landscape (right home button)

Portrait (bottom home button)
```

and when I run the app it now starts in Landscape (left home button) as this is now top of the list. Which is fine

BUT

when I add

```
'Initial interface orientation'[UIInterfaceOrientation]
```

and set it to

```
Landscape (right home button)
```

Its ignored and the first item in the array is used instead

```
Landscape (left home button)
```

I checked shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and it only blocks Portrait upside down

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I also added debug code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait");
    }else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
            NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown");
    }else  if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
            NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft");
    }else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UNKNOWN");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

and I get

```
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

so you can see it does try an use

```
'Initial interface orientation'[UIInterfaceOrientation]
```

and set it to

```
Landscape (right home button)
```

but then it switches back to the first item in the array is used instead

```
Landscape (left home button)
```

am I doing something wrong?
This is a simple SINGLE VIEW Xcode Template project... just add the debug code.

Comment: just checked another project and they delete all orientations in the array except the one they want. Then set Initial to same value.
Wont work on ipad, should support them all AND set inital.

Answer (score 16):

Despite the documentation, `UIInterfaceOrientation` is ignored. Use only `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`. To specify which one you prefer to launch into, make it the *first* one listed in `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`.

It is then up to your individual view controllers to rule out any orientations they refuse to adopt.

Answer (score 1):

Initial Interface Orientation did not worked for me. I just **changed the sequence in supported interface orientation** and it worked. [image]

Comment: Absolutely correct! Plus: the order of the items is important here!