# How to make an app launch in correct landscape orientation without rotating 180° at launch?

Tags: ios, ios7

I am facing a weird issue with a landscape-only app. It rotates just fine to landscape left or right, but when the app launches it rotates 180 degrees instead of just launching in the correct orientation.

I did everything I could find on StackOverflow and Google. The info plist contains:

[image]
[image]

Tested: iOS 7.1 completely ignores the initial launch orientation setting in the plist. I tried both left and right, and then **deleted** the key from info plist. No effect. App always launches in landscape with home button on the left, ignoring this setting.
[image]

When retrying, I delete the app and clean the build.

In App Delegate, I have this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

In the root view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Some landscape apps like Tiny Wings launch in the correct orientation so I know something is wrong with my project. What is the secret sauce to get this working?

Answer (score 4):

First you don't need the three methods you have in your `AppDelegate` as they are meant for controllers and won't get called anyway.

You could implement `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` (iOS 6+) although it says it's not needed with the correct keys in your `Info.plist`:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method returns the total set of interface orientations supported
>   by the app. When determining whether to rotate a particular view
>   controller, the orientations returned by this method are intersected
>   with the orientations supported by the root view controller or topmost
>   presented view controller. The app and view controller must agree
>   before the rotation is allowed.
>
> If you do not implement this method, the app uses the values in the
>   UIInterfaceOrientation key of the app’s Info.plist as the default
>   interface orientations.

But if your problem is on iOS 6+ I would give it a try as it could be an Apple bug.

Also you could just return all orientations in your controller methods to keep it simple.

---

In sum:

- Delete the methods you posted from your `AppDelegate`, they won't get called.
- Return all orientations in your controllers.
- Then control your preferred orientations with your `Info.plist` (any iOS version).

Optional, if problems persist:

- Try implementing `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` in your `AppDelegate` (iOS 6+ only), which in general shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Does this method belong into AppDelegate, the Window, the RootViewController or all of them?

Comment: Like this?

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

Comment: Problem is also iOS 7. Everywhere. I also have a custom UIWindow subclass.

Comment: Custom `UIWindow` classes shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

iOS always launches an app into the same interface orientation, (the first one declared by the app, I believe) and then rotates after launch.  This is the intended behavior because it simplifies some aspects of development.

However, I believe the answer to this question is the solution you're looking for:
[iOS: Initial interface orientation[UIInterfaceOrientation] being ignored in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298232/ios-initial-interface-orientationuiinterfaceorientation-being-ignored-in-plis)

Answer (score 1):

AS far I got your question ,this might help you out. You could simply tick landscape(right/left) mode in device orientation in general setting. [image: Tick orientation which you want]

No need to change plist or anything. This helped me as I created a game for landscape mode so it just opens up in landscape mode and no rotating effects.

Comment: Well that is exactly what I did and it doesn't work. App always launches in same landscape orientation and then rotates 180 degrees around if wrong one.

Comment: I tried it again...See I ticked landscape Right then open app in landscape left mode(simulator) then turned around and around but still no rotation. See if you tick both landscape right and left then only there will that rotation effect. Ok?¿

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of values for `Supported interface orientations` and `Supported interface orientations (iPad)`. So, `Landscape (right home button)` should go first and `Landscape (left home button)` should go second in those lists.

Also, you can safely remove `Initial interface orientation` from `.plist`. And those three methods related to interface orientation handling in `AppDelegate` and `RootViewController`.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the order doesn't have any effect.