# iOS launch screen orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, launch

We have a Objective C app that uses a launchScreen storyboard.  The app is pinned to landscape left or right in the general settings.  What we see is during the launch, when the home button is on the left, the launch screen displays upside down, then rotates around.

Does anyone know of a way to have the launch screen respect the current orientation of the device?

Comment: Update:  It is not just the launch screen, it appears that the order of Supported interface orientations plays in here.  The first one in the list is how the app will launch.  Anyone have a way around this, seems silly to me that there would be this limitation.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12906536/1107063

Comment: Rob: Did you get hold of it by that link? I still have the same problem as you have. Any input would be appreciated. :)